# Run foxpro .prg with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, visual-foxpro

well basically I have a bit of a problem and I'm at a block at the moment, I'm trying to use vbs to run a foxpro .prg file , normally I would have to right click the .prg then click run then foxpro ask me for the possessing date and stuff but i can use sendkeys for that i figured  I don't mind if its not hidden any help will be greatly appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can double-click the PRG file and it opens in FoxPro (meaning the PRG extension has a shell association with the FoxPro executable) then you should be able to use the `Run` method of VBScript's `Shell` object to "launch" the PRF file directly:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & strPathToPrgFile & Chr(34)
```

Otherwise, you could always launch FoxPro and pass the PRG file as a param:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & strPathToFoxProExe & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strPathToPrgFile & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it tonight and let you know how it turns out  , thanks again

Comment: Ok so its not really doing what i need it to do it just runs the file like if i double clicked it, the two things that happen are 1. if i double click it, it opens with fox pro but just shows the prg script 2. i right click the prg file then click run it asks me for it then run the prg then i get the prossesing date box and stuff and this is the code i used>               objShell.Run("Z:\Reports\W***\Agent\Prg\****V2.0.prg"), 1, True < is there any way i can emulate the right click run ?